# Giving maximum height and width equally to canvas in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am trying to set a layout for my web app. I want to have 2 canvases to fill most of the window and 4 image buttons at the bottom. **Here is what I am trying to achieve**:

[image: What I want]

But I get it all screwed in the browser. The canvas are small! No matter what I put as height or width of the dives or the canvas itself in the CSS file. I want them to be be ideally 800x600 and resize with the same ratio if the window is being resized.

[image: Real result]

Here are my HTML and CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #DC0A2F;
  height: 50px;
}

header img.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 13px 0px 13px;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-weight: revert;
}

header a:hover {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}

main.index {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #888888;
}

main img.menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  font-size: 130%;
}

th {
  background-color: #888888;
  border-color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #888888;
  border-right: solid 1px #888888;
}

img.index {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.ergebniss {
  margin: 50px;
}

svg.header {
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.vorschau {
  margin: 100px;
}

canvas{ border: 1px solid black; background-color: red;}

.footPreviewContainer {
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

#previewWrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#previewWrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: auto;
}

#leftCanvas #rightCanvas {
  height: 800px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #DC0A2F;
}

.previewButtons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>WebSocket Echo Client</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fitToPage" id="canvas"></div>
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="./content/GUI/logo_weiss.svg" alt="Elten Logo" onclick="goHome();" />
    <a href="#Herunterfahren">Herunterfahren</a>
    <a href="#Neustart">Neustart</a>
  </header>

  <!-- HERE IS THE ISSURE -->

  <div id="previewWrapper" class="footPreviewContainer">
    <canvas id="leftCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="rightCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="previewButtons">
    <img id="actionButtonPreview" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_preview.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="initWebSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonStop" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="stopWebSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonMeasure" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="checkSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonSendMessage" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="sendMessage();">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `display:flex;` on the preview container and set the height using `vh` (view height) units. The defaults will cause the children canvases to stretch to fill the height, and you can then choose how to align them. They are set to `justify-content: space-around;` in the below snippet which evenly divides any free space on both sides of the children elements.

```
#previewWrapper {
  height: 85vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

canvas {
  width: 46vw;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #DC0A2F;
  height: 50px;
}

header img.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 13px 0px 13px;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-weight: revert;
}

header a:hover {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}

main.index {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #888888;
}

main img.menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  font-size: 130%;
}

th {
  background-color: #888888;
  border-color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #888888;
  border-right: solid 1px #888888;
}

img.index {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.ergebniss {
  margin: 50px;
}

svg.header {
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.vorschau {
  margin: 100px;
}

canvas{ border: 1px solid black; background-color: red;}

.footPreviewContainer {
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

#previewWrapper {
  height: 85vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

canvas {
  width: 46vw;
 }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>WebSocket Echo Client</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fitToPage" id="canvas"></div>
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="./content/GUI/logo_weiss.svg" alt="Elten Logo" onclick="goHome();" />
    <a href="#Herunterfahren">Herunterfahren</a>
    <a href="#Neustart">Neustart</a>
  </header>

  <!-- HERE IS THE ISSURE -->

  <div id="previewWrapper" class="footPreviewContainer">
    <canvas id="leftCanvas"></canvas>
    <canvas id="rightCanvas"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="previewButtons">
    <img id="actionButtonPreview" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_preview.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="initWebSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonStop" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="stopWebSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonMeasure" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="checkSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonSendMessage" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="sendMessage();">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have to add a bit css. I add it directly to style inline, like this you can fix it easily

```
  <div id="previewWrapper" class="footPreviewContainer" style="display:flex; height:auto; max-height:600px;">
    <canvas id="leftCanvas" style="height:100%;width:800px;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="rightCanvas" style="height:100%;width:800px;"></canvas>
  </div>
```

The first thing is to fix the height of the previewWrapper. And then width in for the canvas.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #DC0A2F;
  height: 50px;
}

header img.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px 13px 0px 13px;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-weight: revert;
}

header a:hover {
  padding-top: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}

main.index {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #888888;
}

main img.menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  font-size: 130%;
}

th {
  background-color: #888888;
  border-color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #888888;
  border-right: solid 1px #888888;
}

img.index {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.ergebniss {
  margin: 50px;
}

svg.header {
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.vorschau {
  margin: 100px;
}

canvas{ border: 1px solid black; background-color: red;}

.footPreviewContainer {
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center;
}

#previewWrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

#previewWrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: auto;
}

#leftCanvas #rightCanvas {
  height: 800px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  background-color: #DC0A2F;
}

.previewButtons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>WebSocket Echo Client</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fitToPage" id="canvas"></div>
  <header>
    <img class="logo" src="./content/GUI/logo_weiss.svg" alt="Elten Logo" onclick="goHome();" />
    <a href="#Herunterfahren">Herunterfahren</a>
    <a href="#Neustart">Neustart</a>
  </header>

  <!-- HERE IS THE ISSURE -->

  <div id="previewWrapper" class="footPreviewContainer" style="display:flex; height:auto; max-height:600px;">
    <canvas id="leftCanvas" style="height:100%;width:800px;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="rightCanvas" style="height:100%;width:800px;"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div class="previewButtons">
    <img id="actionButtonPreview" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_preview.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="initWebSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonStop" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="stopWebSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonMeasure" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="checkSocket();">
    <img id="actionButtonSendMessage" class="logo" src="./content/GUI/button_messen.svg" alt="Vermessungsbutton" onclick="sendMessage();">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```